# Is there a general algorithm to give result for designing m:1 mux using n:1 muxes where n<m?

Tags: digital-logic

I have seen a lot of examples like using 4:1 muxes to create a single 8:1 mux or using 2:1 muxes to create a single 16:1 mux. However, so far I have not seen a general purpose algorithm which can tell how many muxes of smaller size can be used to create a larger mux and how to connect the select lines to the smaller mux.

For example, how many 4:1 muxes are required to create a 128:1 mux, how will the select lines be connected? Or what if we have a limited number of 8:1 and 4:1 muxes and need to determine if they can be used to create a 128:1 mux at all e.t.c.

Is there a well known algorithm to do this? If it exists, it will have a name to it as well.

Comment: You could probably just sit down with a pencil and paper and draw out a few cases  and extrapolate to figure out the algorithm yourself.

Comment: *quantum*, the rigorous approach is found in an area called 'concrete math' and uses the ideas of recurrences and generating functions. These are "well known" in certain circles. However, a software algorithm (flow-chart) could easily be cobbled up to create useful results and just as @DKNguyen says, it would just be a matter of sitting down with paper and pencil. But I believe a mathy approach could also be used to create a closed solution. Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik have a good book called "Concrete Mathematics" (2nd edition is the one I studied.)

Comment: What kind of mux do you want to use?

Comment: To directly answer your 128 vs 4 question, you know you will need 32 4:1's at the start. The low-order 2 address bits would feed these in common. Then you will need 8 more at the next stage with the next higher order 2 address bits for them. Then you will need 2 more at the next stage, again with 2 more address bits. And finally just one with only one address bit (the other being '0'.) You should be able to visualize this quickly.

Comment: It is the same as calculating number of nodes of (balanced) n-ary tree knowing the number of leaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming \$m\$ and \$n\$ are of powers of \$2\$, and \$m < n\$...

To create an \$n:1\$ mux out of \$m:1\$ muxes, you can calculate the total no. \$m:1\$ muxes, levels of cascading required, and number of \$m:1\$ muxes required in each level by iterating like this:

**pseduocode:**

```
N = n
T = 0 
L = 0
k[] = 0    // all elements zero

while (N >= m) 
{
   N = N/m
   T = T + N 
   k[L] = N
   L = L + 1
}

// n is not a power of m    
if (N != 1) 
{
   L = L + 1       
   number of m:1 muxes needed = T
   number of N:1 muxes needed = 1       
   number of levels required = L       
}

// n is a power of m 
else 
{
   number of m:1 muxes needed = T
   number of levels required = L
}
```

The structure is like an \$m\$-ary tree with \$L\$ number of levels: \$0 \text{ to } L-1\$.

The \$i^{th}\$ level consists of \$k[i]\$ number of \$m:1\$ muxes, where \$i = 0 \text{ to } L-1\$. Each level has a select line of width = \$\text{log}_2m\$.

At the last level, there is room for optimization as you may need only a smaller mux than \$m:1\$ (say \$N:1\$ mux), if \$n\$ is not a power of \$m\$. This level will then have a select line of width = \$\text{log}_2N\$.

Sum of all select line widths in all levels (\$0 \text{ to } L-1\$) should be = \$\text{log}_2n\$.

Global select line of width \$\text{log}_2n\$ have to be decoded like:
{\$S_0\$, \$S_1\$ ...}, where \$S_i\$ is the select line corresponding to \$i^{th}\$ level, and \$i = 0 \text{ to } L-1\$.

Answer (score 1):

Please familiarise yourself with the basic idea of the  Ceiling Function, either by looking at the Excel version or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).
It rounds any decimal number up to the nearest whole number. Thus \$\lceil{24/4}\rceil = 6\$,
\$\lceil{25/4}\rceil = 7\$, \$\lceil{26/4}\rceil = 7\$, \$\lceil{27/4}\rceil = 7\$,  \$\lceil{28/4}\rceil = 7\$,  \$\lceil{29/4}\rceil = 8\$

Assume you want a mux of size N and need to build it with muxes of size n where N>n. Further assume that n is a power of 2 such that \$2^k=n\$, a reasonable assumption as it would be inefficient to build a mux that wasn't.
Then there is an iterative procedure that will generate your required mux.
First level requires \$N_1=\lceil{N/n}\rceil\$ muxes of size n.
Level 2 requires \$N_2=\lceil{N_1/n}\rceil\$ muxes of size n.
And so on until\$N_r=1\$
You will require a total of \$N_1+N_2+...N_r\$ muxes of size n
and \$k*r\$ address lines.

Example N=100, n=8 (k=3)
\$N_1=\lceil{100/8}\rceil = 13\$
\$N_2=\lceil{13/8}\rceil = 2\$
\$N_3=\lceil{2/8}\rceil = 1\$
Hence you would need 13+2+1 = 16 muxes of size 8 using (r=3, k=3) 3*3 = 9 address lines.
Now I agree this is NOT a good or efficient design, particularly as the last mux need only have 2 inputs and 1  address line. It is only to show the method.

If you have a selection of building blocks (muxes) then this is the time to chose a more appropriate one for the last stage.

Your example N=128, n=4 (k=2)
\$N_1=\lceil{128/4}\rceil = 32\$
\$N_2=\lceil{32/4}\rceil = 8\$
\$N_3=\lceil{8/4}\rceil = 2\$
\$N_4=\lceil{2/4}\rceil = 1\$
You need 32+8+2+1 = 43 muxes of size 4 and (k=2, r=4) 2*4 = 8 address lines.
Again you might consider replacing the \$N_4\$ mux with a 2 input one and use only 7 address lines.

Comment: I see, what about the expression that tells which select lines connect to the muxes at each "level"?

Comment: @quantum231 You would take them in order. N1 would have the k highest order lines, N2 the nest k and so on. In your example, k=2 and you nee 8 select lines S1 - S8 where S1 is the high order line. all 32 N1 muxes take S1 & S2. all 8 N2 muxes take S3 & S4 and so on.